# Android Studio link prebuilt library .so error

Tags: android, gradle, ffmpeg, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm developing an Android app using FFmpeg. I have built FFmpeg into *.so files and put them into jniLibs as follows:

src

--main

----jniLibs

------armeabi

--------libavcodec-57.so

--------libavformat-57.so

--------xx.so

While in grade script, abifilter of ndk is armeabi.

In java files, I have succeeded load these .so files and the built apk also contains them. However, when I use any API (e.g. av_register_all()) of them in a .c file under src/jni folder, build error comes:

Error:(14) undefined reference to 'av_register_all'

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/zhouyf/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

It seems that problem exists in linker. But I found answer that just putting .so files to jniLibs/armeabi will be OK. 
Do I need modify build.gradle file to link those .so files or else?

P.S.

If I don't call the API, the app will run successfully, only with warning: W/linker: libavformat-57.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6ffffffe arg 0x60e0
W/linker: libavformat-57.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6fffffff arg 0x2

Environment:
Android Studio 2.1.1
Mac OS X 10.11.5

Comment: Try to upgrade to AndroiStudio 2.2, and you will get along with the other goodies the built-in debuggable [externalNativeBuild](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/external-c-builds)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add libraries as dependencies when you build by using `ndk-build`.

Disable default `ndk-build`, in your `build.gradle`

```
sourceSets.main {
    jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
    jni.srcDirs = []
}
```

Add your own `ndk-build` task, in your `build.gradle`

```
def ndkDir = properties.getProperty("ndk.dir")

task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        commandLine ndkDir + File.separator + 'ndk-build.cmd', '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath
    } else {
        commandLine ndkDir + File.separator + 'ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}
```

Finally, in your `Android.mk`, add the libraries like this.

```
LOCAL_MODULE := # ...
# ...
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -L/path/of/the/libraries -lavcodec-57 -lavformat-57 ...
```

Comment: The IDE is Android Studio, which generates Android.mk automatically. Any modification of Android.mk doesn't work

Comment: I checked my Android.mk and found there are not -lavcodec-57 in it. But if I modify it manually, gradle will undo my modification

Comment: Done! Thanks for your hint! I disabled the default ndk-build and write an Android.mk and executed ndk-build command both manually.

Comment: What a pity that the default function of Android Studio cannot handle this problem

Comment: @ZhouYufeng It has this feature in the experimental build plugin. check [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental#TOC-Ndk-Integration)